# SQL trigger for ERP system

Tags: sql, triggers, erp

I've been working on getting this trigger to work for the past 2 days with no luck. I've re-written it a couple different ways and still can't get it to work

```
SELECT * 
FROM Estim 
WHERE PartNo = '[SearchVal1]' 
  AND ReOrdLevel > QtyOnHand + QtyOnRes + (SELECT SUM(QtyToStock) 
                                           FROM OrderDet 
                                           WHERE OrderDet.PartNo = Estim.PartNo 
                                             AND OrderDet.Status ='Open')
```

It is supposed to alert one of our sales members to reorder a stock item when and part number is below the reorder level.

The query adds the units on reserve, on hand, and the ones currently in the process of being created that will go to stock.

It seems to break when I add the stock part which needs to add all the open orders of that part number together and then add it to the reserve and on hand.

Pretty new to writing queries so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms product? (Most of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to triggers...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the built in inventory low trigger? Go to customers then hit f4 setup any desired modifications and start the trigger server file tservado.exe. or you can use that trigger to get the syntax that is used. I do not have access to the software at the moment but that should work for you.

Comment: I have tried using the pre-made one, but it doesn't compare the correct fields to the reorder level (we have our stock system set up poorly) so i need to be able to also look at the orders in process that match the part number to correctly gauge if it needs an order placed.